# Inter process communication via shared memory

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying do an inter process communication using shared memory. Here is the structure definition.

```
#define SHM_SIZE (519430400)
test_ht *CommandLine_Buffer;

typedef struct
{
    int             a;
    int             testnum;
    st_cl           cli[3];
}test_ht;

typedef struct
{
    tHT             CliInfo;
} st_cl;

typedef struct
{
    int x;
} tHT;

Shared memory is created as below

    int fd;
    int ret_v;
    void* addr;
    int i;

    fd = shm_open("SharedBuf.shm", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
    ret_v = ftruncate(fd, SHM_SIZE);
    SharedBuffer = mmap(NULL, SHM_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, SEEK_SET);

    I access the structure members as below

    CommandLine_Buffer->cli[i].CliInfo.x
```

Here I can read and write `a` and `testnum` across procesess. Shared memory is created successfully.
At the same time I can access

```
CommandLine_Buffer->cli[0].CliInfo.x and CommandLine_Buffer->cli[1].CliInfo.x
```

Am unable to get `CommandLine_Buffer->cli[2].CliInfo.x`.

Any tips to debug this or any idea why am unable to read the last location.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And please tell us in more detail how you're "unable to get" the data.

Comment: And why do you need almost 500 MiB for a single (and much smaller) structure?